# Does the android NDK compiler support inline assembly? (ie asm or __asm keywords?)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Just wondering if andorid NDK supports direct embedding of asm?

```
asm{
//lots of strange asm instructions...
 }
```

If so, I presume you'd have to get some refference to the instruction sets of the specfic arm achitecture - where would you find these?

Thanks,
Steve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Android NDK uses GCC, so you can safely look at GCC documentation.

As for the specific ARM instructions, something like [ARM architecture](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.set.architecture/index.html) may be a good starting point.

Comment: is the GCC compiler version specific to andorid? Or can I find the documentation in any linux based resource? Thanks

Comment: The compiler itself is standard. The NDK r6 for example uses GCC v4.4.3. The NDK does have it's own build system and the like to wrap it all up however. That said, yes the standard GCC documentation should do.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @NuSkooler this is another useful resource

[ARM GCC inline assembler cookbook](http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html)